# Can I display Javascript Content HTML

Tags: javascript, html, document.write

I'm trying to get a hidden form CLASS to show onclick of a class.

Heres my code:

```
<div class="product">
    <input type="submit" class="clickme" />

     <script>
     document.getElementsByClassName('clickme')[0].onclick = function(){
         document.write('<form class="etc"><label>Etc</label><select></select>');
     };
     </script>
</div>

<div class="product">
    <input type="submit" class="clickme" />

     <script>
     document.getElementsByClassName('clickme')[0].onclick = function(){
         document.write('<form class="etc"><label>Etc</label><select></select>');
     };
     </script>
</div>

<div class="product">
    <input type="submit" class="clickme" />

     <script>
     document.getElementsByClassName('clickme')[0].onclick = function(){
         document.write('<form class="etc"><label>Etc</label><select></select>');
     };
     </script>
</div>
```

The forms inside the scripts are styled.

I want the click to show only the content in the script, however nothing is working, Alerts work fine - So my question is can i use HTML in Scripts? And if so - based on what you see in this code, how can i do that?

Comment: You can't use `document.write` to inject contents after the document is already loaded. Use the DOM instead.

Comment: Could you please elaborate, very new to javascript

Comment: you can create forms hidden and onclick show them, change style from hidden to visible.

Comment: Hey Junior, I can do that with ID's however with Classes I run into the problem of them all opening, do you have a way of onclick to open only the one inside the product container associated with the same 'clickme'?

Comment: @user3405517 I fear that just giving code or throwing ideas will confuse you. My tip is to learn some basics of JavaScript first, start with how to inject elements at runtime, or as other comment here mentioned how to show hidden elements at runtime. Both will have same final effect.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not really what you expect as answer but I believe you can pretty much what you are trying to do with  [jquery click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) and [jquery html](https://api.jquery.com/html/).

Hope this helps